# Forms: ComboBox: How to set "null" value

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, .net-6.0

I have a class derived from the standard `ComboBox` and there I set items to the `DataSource`

```
public sealed class TagComboBox : ComboBox
{
    public void SetItems(List<Tag> tags)
    {
        this.DisplayMember = nameof(TagComboBoxItem.Display);
        this.ValueMember = nameof(TagComboBoxItem.Value);

        this.DataSource = tags
            .Select(t => new TagComboBoxItem(t))
            .OrderBy(i => i.Display)
            .ToList();
    }

    private sealed class TagComboBoxItem
    {
        public string Display { get; }
        public Tag Value { get; }

        public TagComboBoxItem(Tag tag)
        {
            this.Display = tag?.Name ?? "(No Tag)";
            this.Value = tag;
        }
    }
}
```

In some cases a "none" item is also available which I insert at the first position:

```
tags.Insert(0, (Tag)null); //cast was a test but did not help
tagComboBox.SetItems(tags);
```

When setting any real tag to the `SelectedValue` property, it works flawlessly. However when trying to set `tagComboBox.SelectedValue = null;` I get `System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Arg_ParamName_Name'`

In this particular case I can fall back to simply setting `tagComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;` because I know extactly where the "none" item is but I don't understand why I am allowed to add a `ValueMember` item as `null` but then not allowed to set it as the `SelectedValue`.

Answer (score 0):

That's because of how the Windows Forms CurrencyManager, which is what is used to locate an item when setting SelectedValue, works.

This is the code that throws the exception you see:

```
internal int Find(PropertyDescriptor property, Object key, bool keepIndex) {
    if (key == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("key");

    if (property != null && (list is IBindingList) && ((IBindingList)list).SupportsSearching) {
        return ((IBindingList)list).Find(property, key);
    }

    if (property != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) {
            object value = property.GetValue(list[i]);
            if (key.Equals(value)) {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Value of 'Key' is what you set in SelectedValue.

It would require more investigation to understand the reason why it has been implemented this way, but I assume you're just interested to know if what you're trying to do can be done, and from the code above, it can't.

Maybe you can override the SelectedValue property and if passed value is null set the index there?

For example:

```
public new object SelectedValue
    {
        get => base.SelectedValue;
        set
        {
            if (value is null && _nullIndex >= 0) {
                SelectedIndex = _nullIndex;
                return;
            }
            base.SelectedValue = value;
        }
    }
```

You would need to store the _nullIndex value in SetItems in this case.
Something like

```
_nullIndex = tags.IndexOf(tags.FirstOrDefault(t => t is null));
```